# How to coalesce masked array indices for CUDA Kernel

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I have a cuda kernel in python which operates on several arrays, based on applied masks.

The arrays are extremely large in the y dimension, so lots of columns, and a small number of rows.

The masks applied select indices from the arrays that are not necessarily, or often, adjacent to one another. And the condition for the masks are based on strings, so I can't do them within the kernel.

Is there a sensible approach to accessing these arrays in a coalesced way?

The function and the kernel it calls looks something like this:

```
threads_per_block = 256

def func_kernel(S, af, af0, data, i, mask_indices):
    start = cuda.grid(1) 
    stride = cuda.gridsize(1)
     
    for r in range(start, mask_indices.shape[0], stride):
        id_r = mask_indices[r, 0]
        id_c = mask_indices[r,1]
        db1[id_r,id_c] = S[id_r, i] * ((af0[id_r] * af[id_r, i]))
    
    mask_indices = None

def s_af0_af_func(mask, S, af, af0, data, i):
    mask_indices = np.column_stack(np.where(mask))
    if mask_indices.size == 0:
        return
    num_columns_mask = mask_indices.shape[0]
    mask_indices = cuda.to_device(mask_indices)
    func_threads = min(threads_per_block, num_columns_mask)
    blockspergrid = (num_columns_mask + threads_per_block - 1) // threads_per_block
    s_af0_af_func_kernel[blockspergrid, func_threads](S, af, af0, data, i, mask_indices)
    mask_indices = None
```

So id_r and id_c are not necessarily adjacent. As implemented the kernels don't offer any speed-up over a numpy implementation, and I guess this is probably the reason.

Or is there another approach for applying the mask on strings in the kernel?

Any advice welcomed.

Comment: Well, the layout of `S` and `af` are inefficient. There is no magical way to fix that once one the GPU if you read the array once. The only solution I see is to operate on the transposed array and actually create the array in a transposed form when it is created and filled. Regarding the `id_r` and `id_c` indices, it depends on the data distribution. In some case you can benefit from using shared memory (but the cache may already help). Shared memory is small so if the indices are like random on a very large range, with a uniform-like distribution, there is AFAIK not much to do.

Comment: When you say "the kernels don't offer any speed-up over a numpy implementation", that makes me suspicious. How sure are you that this is your only issue? What's your GPU? What is the data type of those arrays? And have you used the [Nvidia Nsight visual profiler](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-systems) to check whether uncoalesced access is your true bottleneck?

Comment: When access is regular, one can transpose the incoming data locally by writing it to shared memory. Due to the random access that is not useful though, because you don't have a single consecutive block of memory that you can put into shared memory.